# Can access to Bluemix container registry be access controlled?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, container-registry

I want only the CI tools or dedicated users to have write access to the Bluemix Docker registry. Developer or cloud admin accounts should not have write access to the registry. How can this be done?

Comment: This document should help you https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_volumes_write.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now issue `read-only` or `read-write` tokens for `IBM Bluemix Container Registry` using the `container-registry` plugin for the `bx` command.

Tokens can either be non-expiring (unless revoked) or expire after 24 hours.

The use case of automating access is well covered by the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/registry_tokens.html#registry_tokens).

Answer (score 1):

At this time it is not possible to have different image access levels for the users in the same cf org.

Answer (score 0):

Security settings for clusters and deployments in IBM Bluemix Container service is documented here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_security.html#cs_security

It may help you in your requirement ...